# Attempting to replace an errant single-quote (') with a comma (using tabular)

Tags: tables

The following section of LaTeX code:

```
  \node [below=of Mesozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Jurassic) {Jurassic Period \\ 199 - 145 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
```

creates in the following image:

[image: Replacing an errant single-quote with a comma]

where there is a single-quote (') after "Bituminous (US/IL)  ' ".

What I'd like to have is a comma immediately following the text "Bituminous (US/IL)" so that the comma (,) separates the "Bituminous (US/IL)" from the "Lignite (CN)".

What am I doing wrong in the code that generates the single-quote, and how can I replace it with a comma (,) ?

I can provide the full LaTeX code if necessary.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Apologies, I've been asked to provide the full LaTeX code:

Note: The above code snippet can be found under "% Mesozoic Era".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Add color package
\usetikzlibrary{trees, positioning, matrix}

\begin{document}

% Define colors
\definecolor{LigniteColor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0} % Green
\definecolor{BituminousColor}{rgb}{0,0,1} % Blue
\definecolor{AnthraciteColor}{rgb}{1,0,0} % Red

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, every node/.style={draw=black, align=center, shape=rectangle, rounded corners}, sloped]
  \node (Coal) at (0,0) {Coal Deposits};

  % Cenozoic Era
  \node [below left=of Coal, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-3cm] (Cenozoic) {Cenozoic Era \\ 66 Mya to Present};
  \node [below left=of Cenozoic, yshift=0cm, text width=3cm] (Quaternary) {Quaternary Period \\ < 2.6 Mya \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (DE, PL, TR, US/ND, US/TX)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, CN, IN, AU, RU)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below=of Cenozoic, yshift=-1cm] (Tertiary) {Tertiary Period \\ 66 - 2.6 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, CN, IN, AU, RU)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{AnthraciteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Anthracite \\ (US/PA)
    \end{tabular}}
  };

  % Mesozoic Era
  \node [below=of Coal, yshift=-2cm] (Mesozoic) {Mesozoic Era \\ 251 - 66 Mya};
  \node [below left=of Mesozoic, yshift=-1cm, xshift=0.5cm] (Cretaceous) {Cretaceous Period \\ 145 - 66 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below=of Mesozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Jurassic) {Jurassic Period \\ 199 - 145 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below right=of Mesozoic, yshift=-3cm] (Triassic) {Triassic Period \\ 251 - 199 Mya \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };

  % Paleozoic Era
  \node [below right=of Coal, yshift=-7cm, xshift=3cm] (Paleozoic) {Paleozoic Era \\ 541 - 251 Mya};
  \node [below left=of Paleozoic, yshift=-1cm] (Permian) {Permian Period \\ 299 - 251 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, AU, RU)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{AnthraciteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Anthracite \\ (RU)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below=of Paleozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Carboniferous) {Carboniferous Period \\ 359 - 299 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, AU, RU)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (US/ND)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below right=of Paleozoic, yshift=-3cm] (Devonian) {Devonian Period \\ 419 - 359 Mya \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (US/ND)
    \end{tabular}}
  };

  \draw (Coal) -- (Cenozoic);
  \draw (Cenozoic) -- (Quaternary);
  \draw (Cenozoic) -- (Tertiary);

  \draw (Coal) -- (Mesozoic);
  \draw (Mesozoic) -- (Cretaceous);
  \draw (Mesozoic) -- (Jurassic);
  \draw (Mesozoic) -- (Triassic);

  \draw (Coal) -- (Paleozoic);
  \draw (Paleozoic) -- (Permian);
  \draw (Paleozoic) -- (Carboniferous);
  \draw (Paleozoic) -- (Devonian);

  % Full Legend position
  \node [below=of Tertiary, yshift=-1cm, xshift=0cm, text width=10cm, align=left] (Legend) {
    \begin{center}
      \textbf{\Large Legend:}
    \end{center}
    $\bullet$ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{\textbf{Lignite}}: Also known as brown coal, forms over tens of thousands to a few million years. Lowest rank of coal, lower heat content, higher moisture. Found in Germany (DE), Poland (PL), Turkey (TR), United States (North Dakota, Texas) (US/ND, US/TX), China (CN).\\[0.5em]
    $\bullet$ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{\textbf{Bituminous}}: Higher-grade coal, forms over millions of years. Undergoes increased pressure and temperature, higher carbon content than lignite. Found in United States (Appalachian region, Illinois Basin) (US/IL), China (CN), India (IN), Australia (AU), Russia (RU).\\[0.5em]
    $\bullet$ \textcolor{AnthraciteColor}{\textbf{Anthracite}}: Highest rank of coal, forms over long timeframes. High carbon content, low impurities, highest energy content. Found in United States (Pennsylvania) (US/PA), Russia (RU), China (CN).
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Using David Carlisle's [b] replaces the single-quote (') with a comma, but then the comma is sometimes preceded with spaces, e.g.:

[image: The [b] replaces single-quote (') with comma, but leaves extra leading spaces.]

```
 \node [below=of Mesozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Jurassic) {Jurassic Period \\ 199 - 145 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL)
    \end{tabular}}, \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
```

**UPDATE 3:** Using comments from David Carlisle and Jasper Habicht, I've replaced the single-quote (') with a comma and removed the extra spaces b4 the comma. Jasper was helpful with a correction to my syntax to "use an en dash and not a hyphen" for the date ranges. Thank you both.

```
  \node [below=of Mesozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Jurassic) {Jurassic Period \\ 199--145 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
```

For those who may need it sometime in the future, the full revised code follows (Note: The Quaternary Period node still need a bit of work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Add color package
\usetikzlibrary{trees, positioning, matrix}

\begin{document}

% Define colors
\definecolor{LigniteColor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0} % Green
\definecolor{BituminousColor}{rgb}{0,0,1} % Blue
\definecolor{AnthraciteColor}{rgb}{1,0,0} % Red

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, every node/.style={draw=black, align=center, shape=rectangle, rounded corners}, sloped]
  \node (Coal) at (0,0) {Coal Deposits};

  % Cenozoic Era
  \node [below left=of Coal, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-3cm] (Cenozoic) {Cenozoic Era \\ 66 Mya to Present};
  \node [below left=of Cenozoic, yshift=0cm, text width=3cm] (Quaternary) {Quaternary Period \\ < 2.6 Mya \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (DE, PL, TR, US/ND, US/TX),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, CN, IN, AU, RU)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below=of Cenozoic, yshift=-1cm] (Tertiary) {Tertiary Period \\ 66--2.6 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, CN, IN, AU, RU),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{AnthraciteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Anthracite \\ (US/PA)
    \end{tabular}}
  };

  % Mesozoic Era
  \node [below=of Coal, yshift=-2cm] (Mesozoic) {Mesozoic Era \\ 251--66 Mya};
  \node [below left=of Mesozoic, yshift=-1cm, xshift=0.5cm] (Cretaceous) {Cretaceous Period \\ 145--66 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below=of Mesozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Jurassic) {Jurassic Period \\ 199--145 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below right=of Mesozoic, yshift=-3cm] (Triassic) {Triassic Period \\ 251--199 Mya \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (CN)
    \end{tabular}}
  };

  % Paleozoic Era
  \node [below right=of Coal, yshift=-7cm, xshift=3cm] (Paleozoic) {Paleozoic Era \\ 541--251 Mya};
  \node [below left=of Paleozoic, yshift=-1cm] (Permian) {Permian Period \\ 299--251 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{AnthraciteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Anthracite \\ (RU)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below=of Paleozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Carboniferous) {Carboniferous Period \\ 359--299 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      Bituminous \\ (US/IL, AU, RU),
    \end{tabular}} \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (US/ND)
    \end{tabular}}
  };
  \node [below right=of Paleozoic, yshift=-3cm] (Devonian) {Devonian Period \\ 419--359 Mya \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Lignite \\ (US/ND)
    \end{tabular}}
  };

  \draw (Coal) -- (Cenozoic);
  \draw (Cenozoic) -- (Quaternary);
  \draw (Cenozoic) -- (Tertiary);

  \draw (Coal) -- (Mesozoic);
  \draw (Mesozoic) -- (Cretaceous);
  \draw (Mesozoic) -- (Jurassic);
  \draw (Mesozoic) -- (Triassic);

  \draw (Coal) -- (Paleozoic);
  \draw (Paleozoic) -- (Permian);
  \draw (Paleozoic) -- (Carboniferous);
  \draw (Paleozoic) -- (Devonian);

  % Full Legend position
  \node [below=of Tertiary, yshift=-1cm, xshift=0cm, text width=10cm, align=left] (Legend) {
    \begin{center}
      \textbf{\Large Legend:}
    \end{center}
    $\bullet$ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{\textbf{Lignite}}: Also known as brown coal, forms over tens of thousands to a few million years. Lowest rank of coal, lower heat content, higher moisture. Found in Germany (DE), Poland (PL), Turkey (TR), United States (North Dakota, Texas) (US/ND, US/TX), China (CN).\\[0.5em]
    $\bullet$ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{\textbf{Bituminous}}: Higher-grade coal, forms over millions of years. Undergoes increased pressure and temperature, higher carbon content than lignite. Found in United States (Appalachian region, Illinois Basin) (US/IL), China (CN), India (IN), Australia (AU), Russia (RU).\\[0.5em]
    $\bullet$ \textcolor{AnthraciteColor}{\textbf{Anthracite}}: Highest rank of coal, forms over long timeframes. High carbon content, low impurities, highest energy content. Found in United States (Pennsylvania) (US/PA), Russia (RU), China (CN).
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The output is showing a comma but it is next to a vertically centred `tabular` where do you want it to appear? why not place it in the tabular?

Comment: You could use `\begin{tabular}[b]` so the comma aligns with the last line or simply remove the nested tabular, which don't seem to be needed.

Comment: @David Carlisle - The [b] works to replace the single-quote (') with a coma, but the comma is then sometimes preceded by one or two spaces. How do I eliminate the extra spaces b4 the comma?

Comment: What use do these `tabular`s have? Why don't you just put the text into the node directly? Then there won't be any spaces. Or put the comma inside the tabular cell (but outside the `\textcolor` command).

Comment: Apart from that and unrelated to your question: if you use a dash to denote "to", you should probably use an en dash and not a hyphen. As far as I know, it should be `419--359 Mya` and not `419 - 359 Mya`.

Comment: you have specified a centred tabular and UL/IL is shorter than Bituminous  so naturally if you place a comma after the tabular there is space in the last cell.  You could put the comma in the cell after US/IL or not have the nested tabular at all, the layout seems very odd and it's hard to guess your intent here.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - Thanks for the -- tip! I'm wading into a field that is not my own, so I'm new to the syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - Re: Why don't you just put the text into the node directly? How do I do that? Apologies for my ignorance ...

Comment: @David Carlisle - I see what you mean ... How do I fix? I realize you don't need the credit/points, but if you can just submit the code snippet for the "Jurassic Period" node, I'd love to accept your answer.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - Ditto for you.

Comment: @EconomicRent Just type, for example: `\node [below=of Mesozoic, yshift=-2cm] (Jurassic) {Jurassic Period \\ 199--145 Mya \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{Bituminous} \\ \textcolor{BituminousColor}{(US/IL)}, \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{Lignite} \\ \textcolor{LigniteColor}{(CN)}};`.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - OK ... it WORKS! How can I accept your answer? All I need is a code snippet!

Comment: @David Carlisle - I'd like to accept yours or Jasper Habicht's comments as answers so one of you get the credit. All I need is a snippet of code from either of you to then accept you 'answer' for credit. Thank you!!!

Comment: @JasperHabicht can you post:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place a `tabular` inline, it will be aligned vertically centered to the current line by default. In your case, this results in the comma being shifted "upwards" (actually the tabular is shifted). This can be resolved by adding the `[b]` option to the `tabular`, which will align the baseline of the last row to the surrounding text.

Also, a `tabular` always typesets things in boxes of the same width, which is by design. If you put text after a tabular and the text in the last cell happens to be shorter than the whole tabular, naturally, there will be some space.

Consider the following example where I added rules to show the delimitations of the tabular cells:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

x\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
foo bar \\ 
\hline
baz \\
\hline
\end{tabular}x

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The simplest solution, therefore, would be not to use `tabular`s at all. You just need to take care to select the color for every line separately:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define colors
\definecolor{LigniteColor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0} % Green
\definecolor{BituminousColor}{rgb}{0,0,1} % Blue
\definecolor{AnthraciteColor}{rgb}{1,0,0} % Red

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.7, 
    every node/.style={
        align=center, 
        draw,
        rounded corners
    }
  ]

  \node (Jurassic) {
    Jurassic Period \\ 
    199--145 Mya \\ 
    \textcolor{BituminousColor}{Bituminous} \\ 
    \textcolor{BituminousColor}{(US/IL)}, \\ 
    \textcolor{LigniteColor}{Lignite} \\ 
    \textcolor{LigniteColor}{(CN)}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]